# Do I have the right interface after installing GIMP(edit photos software) on Mac?

Tags: mac, applications, install

After GIMP installation, I could see the proper interface( top toolbars and  two sidebars) on Window but there is only one toolbar on Mac even so I've tried different versions of GIMP....

I could see top toolbar with File, Select, View and so on.

I watch the video that show that after installation, there are supposed to be right and left toolbars in additional to the top that I've already have.

It was suggested to get those toolbars from Tools menu if those toolbars are not available.

I've try to check some options from Tools but it is not look as right and left toolbars...

How to see the left and right toolbars and start to edit photos using GIMP or if  I can start edit photos using just top toolbar that I've already had?

Comment: GIMP menu > Windows > Single-Window Mode Then download the GIMP User Manual at [https://www.gimp.org/docs/](https://www.gimp.org/docs/) and **read it**! Then I'd start with having a look at: [https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the hold reviewed.

Comment: I edited the question to make clear that I want to make sure that my interface is correct after downloading and installation software. I could not use  linked post provided before establishing if my interface is correct.

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on the issue at hand. What probably would have helped in your case are two screenshots showing your screen (without toolbars) and the tutorial you are referring to (with the toolbars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the tool panels in GIMP 2.8.22 need to follow next steps depending from source  of downloading:

1. If you  download GIMP from  trusted mirror servers:

Gimp menu > preference > reset
Gimp menu > Windows > Single-Window Model

2. If you  download GIMP from  sources:

Gimp menu >Windows > Single-Window Model

In the earlier version 2.8.18 I could see tool panels immediately after downloading GIMP but for some reasons everything was in in Russian. So, I’ve use the latest version GIMP 2.8.22 following the steps as above.